# Does vanilla Ec2 support anything similar to the termination hooks supported by auto-scaling?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've got a set of machines which are stopped and started nightly for cost management.    They are not in an ASG, because the servers have different purposes/are owned by different users/etc.

I would like to handle the stops more gracefully.  Since there are several flavors of machines, I would like to handle this as a callback on each instance itself.

Does Ec2 support anything similar to the termination hooks that are baked into auto-scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll go through a standard Linux shutdown, so you can setup a service with a shutdown script to do whatever you like.